# How to create a regular expression to find an embedded dollar sign?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I am looking for a string like this: `">$3.45` in some HTML (I'm screen scraping), using this string as a regular expression:  `@"\">\\$"`

The problem is that since the `$` is a Regex character (*match at end of line*) my target is not found.

How do I write this string expression so NSRegularExpression will find the embedded `">$` in my HTML?

Comment: The backslash before `$` should prevent it from being treated as a regexp character.

Comment: @Barmar - You've answered the question by editing it to be correct, so now its confusing to everyone as there is no problem...

Comment: @CRD All I did was fix the markdown, changing boldface to code markup. I didn't change any of the characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\` is *both* the Objective-C string escape character *and* the regular-expression escape character... so to escape the `$` you need to use:

```
@"\">\\$"
```

which creates a string containing a single `\`, and then that backslash is seen by `NSRegularExpression` and used to escape the `$`.

**Note: At the time of writing this answer the question has been edited by a third party to remove the original problem!**

Comment: The double backslash was in the original question. You just couldn't see it because he used the wrong markup (double asterisks for bold instead of backticks for code)

Comment: @Barmer - I'm guessing it was only there so it was visible in the question, or the OP wouldn't have had the issue they reported. Anyway, I'm sure the OP knows the answer by now, one way or another! :-)

Comment: You don't need to double a backslash to make it visible in bold text, although if you DO double it you'll only see one of them, which is what you saw.